# Javascript: parameter takes a random value when not passed in a callback function

Tags: javascript

I am doing an ajax poll periodically. To achieve the same I have the following line of code:

```
window.setInterval(pollForBids, 5000);
```

The function pollForBids is defined as follows:

```
function pollForBids(supplierId){
    alert(supplierId);
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url : "/enterprize-sourcing/refreshBids.do",
      async : true,
      cache : false,
      data  : {action   : "refreshList", 
               eventId  : eventId,
        lastRetrieveTime: makeFinite(latestBidTime, 0),
             supplierId : makeFinite(supplierId, "")},
      success: function(xml){
        refreshBids(xml);
      }
    });
}
```

I have other places in the code where I need the parameter, but in this particular case I do not. But, the alert gives me a random integer value every 5 seconds. Shouldn't it always be undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your function in an anonymous function in the setInterval:

```
  window.setInterval( function() {
      pollForBids();
  }, 5000);
```

This will prevent the random number from being passed into the pollForBids function.

Comment: Yes that works, but I wanted to know where was that random value coming from?

Answer (score 3):

As the Mozilla Developer Center states: "setInterval() will pass the number of milliseconds late the callback was called into the callback function".

[MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)

Usually of course the callback function you pass to `setInterval` takes no parameters, so you're getting this "milliseconds late" value in your `supplierId` parameter.

Also be warned that `setInterval` will be called every 5 seconds whether your callback has completed or not.

Comment: Fascinating!  The recursive setTimeout is one of the reasons why I love JavaScript.  The MDC resource is a good find!  +1

Comment: But why is that "milliseconds late" value random? I get numbers like -15, 6168, -20, 436 during various iterations

Comment: Because your PC and the browser are doing other work (we're not talking single-threading here, just take a look at Activity Monitor or Task Manager to see the number of different processes executing on your machine), that work is essentially random in nature, and therefore the number of milliseconds late will reflect that randomness? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use something like

```
function pollForBids(supplierId){
if (typeof supplierId == "undefined") {
    supplierId = "default value";
  }

   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url : "/enterprize-sourcing/refreshBids.do",
      async : true,
      cache : false,
      data  : {action   : "refreshList", 
               eventId  : eventId,
        lastRetrieveTime: makeFinite(latestBidTime, 0),
             supplierId : makeFinite(supplierId, "")},
      success: function(xml){
        refreshBids(xml);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: No, the supplierId parameter is not undefined here. It already contains a random value...